# When I click the "build now" link in Jenkins, I only want that to build one time but it builds twice

Tags: jenkins

I am completely new to using Jenkins. I'm going through some "step-by-step" videos by RagHav Pal and have reached the point where I have made a batch file that runs command lines when I hit the "Build Now" link. It has been established in the "Build" and "Execute Windows batch command" area of the configuration "Build Environment" tab.

The build is happening as expected, and I do expect some of the Robot Framework Test Cases to fail (which they do). The problem is this: When the build is happening, it is queueing up another build right behind it. It then runs that build too when the first one is done? This queueing continues. Builds keep on building and I have to hit the "x" on the queued build to stop this madness.

I have no idea why it's rebuilding, nor do I know what I've done to cause this. I need the details please, if anyone can help. I want one build... period! Nothing more.

THINGS I HAVE TRIED:

I've tried restarting Jenkins after upgrading any plugins that looked like they needed upgrades.

I've started Jenkins localhost:9090 using Microsoft Edge and discovered I'll get endless builds. However, if I start Jenkins localhost:9090 using Chrome browser I only get 2 builds. Why this difference? I want 1 build only.

I've taken a look at my java folder to see what is there. It has "jdk-12.0.1" which I believe is used for Eclipse. It has "jdk1.8.0-221" and "jre1.8.0-221" and I renamed each of these folders to something else and restarted Jenkins from command line to see which one is getting used. It is using the "jre1.8.0-221". Should I be running the jdk? Dunno? I put everything back the way it was.

I verified the "Poll SCM" check box is not selected.

THE BATCH FILE:

```
c:  
cd C:\Users\TestLab\Desktop\Workspaces\JenkinsWorkspace\RobotFramework\GoDirectProject1
robot GDTest/GoDirectSuite1.robot
echo Completed
```

EXPECTED AND ACTUAL RESULTS:

I'm expecting the build to happen one time and stop
Actual results are as explained above in "Summarize the Problem"

Comment: I thought this had fixed itself as it began only doing 1 build, so I had answered it with that information. However, now that is still doing 2 builds every time. So I'm leaving it open for "Answer"

Comment: It seems I've stumbled upon a workaround. If I go to my Jenkins workspace that I've setup and then select the "Build Now" from the drop-down list of selectable items, then it only built 1 time.